# Logging in to the mobile application using a phone number and connecting to another API

Tags: android, rest, authentication, firebase-authentication, .net-5

I have an **Android** mobile application.

The application connects to the **API in .NET 5 via REST**

I would like to log in via a phone number (I would like to use **Authenticate with Firebase**)

How to go about this topic?

There are many dangerous ways, but I want to do the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth - is the best and simpiest solution for you.
Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start to get the general info.

Also you will get full guides rigth in Android Studio after connect Firebase Auth to your application.